# How To differentiate this integral

Tags: calculus

If you please could show me (step wise) what $h'(x)$ will be if
$$
h(x)= \int_a^x d\phi \int_a^{\phi}(M(t)-c_0-c_1t)dt
$$
where $c_0$ and $c_1$ are constants.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the fundamental theorem of calculus states that for a continuous function $u \colon [a,b] \to \mathbf R$, the function 
$$ U(x) := \int_a^x u(t)\, dt $$
is differentiable with $U'(x) = u(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. In your case, we have 
$$ h(x) = \int_a^x u(\phi)\, d\phi $$
with 
$$ u(\phi) = \int_a^\phi\bigl(M(t) - c_0 - c_1t \bigr)\, dt $$
Hence, by the fundamental theorem cited above
$$ h'(x) = u(x) = \int_a^x \bigl(M(t) - c_0 - c_1 t \bigr)\, dt. $$

Comment: You are so sweet!

Comment: Dear martini, I'm very sorry I downvoted by an I-don't-even-know-how misclicking. However I could not reverse it now because it has been locked as the system informs me. So if you by any chance need to edit this answer, you may let me know and I'll be very willing to reverse my mis-downvote.

Comment: @Vim edited. $       $

Comment: @martini thanks. I have reversed it and upvoted (I guess that must have been what I'd  intended to do). Cheers.